# ubuntu server unresponsive

Tags: 12.04

Ubuntu server unresponsive 12.04

1) My site is not responding by http:
curl --request GET 'http://mysite.com'
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

(doesn't respond on a web browser either)
2) Tried to ssh into it:
 ssh username@ip
ssh: connect to host ip_address port 22: Operation timed out

Is there another way to remotely check what's wrong with the server, without having to go to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use nmap to see if the host is up or down (running nmap as sudo makes it report more accurately).  I would also suggest running dig or traceroute on your domain in order to make sure that it is not a problem somewhere in between you and your server.

Comment: What is the output of traceroute supposed to indicate? For me it lists some ip addresses and apparently the amount of time it took to reach them followed by a lot of "* * *"

Comment: It was just to make sure you weren't having some sort of other DNS issue that was preventing you from reaching the server.

Comment: If there was a DNS issue, what would the output look like?

Comment: It would give an NXDOMAIN error.

Answer (score 0):

can you try it with ssh -v username@ip ?

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to answer the question (so it shouldn't be deleted) ...but can you expand this by explaining what that command does and why you recommend it?